# Autocomplete Function with Databse, without JQuery Ui and JQuery Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to find a way to program a simple autocomplete function with DB access, using JS, HTML5, CSS, Servlets and JQuery.

However, I can not use JQuery Ui (which is really bad since I do like the autocomplete function because of it's simplicity) or JQuery Plugins.

Datalist did not seem to do the job quite right on chrome (I had to select the element of the list and then click on it again after it has been selected, also it is not supported on Safari and iOS Safari).

Is there a simple way to build something like the JQuery Ui autocomplete function using only JQuery Ui and the rest of my tools? Thank you for your time and advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use twitters typeahead plugin for simple autocompletion.